# ComboBox in DataGrid is being emptied only when ItemsSource depends on row

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, combobox, datagrid

I find myself in a situation where whether or not a given `ComboBox` in a `DataGridRow` is being emptied depends on whether or not its `ItemsSource` is bound to the row in the `DataGrid` or in the parent.

Concretely, consider the following WPF `Window`:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }

    private void Selector_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (((ComboBox)sender).Items.Count == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("This seems unlikely!");
    }
}
```

Then, the following example works as I would expect; that is, the `InvalidOperationException` in `Selector_OnSelectionChanged` is never called, which makes sense to me as there is no empty `ComboBox` involved:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedName}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Names, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}, Mode=FindAncestor}}"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedName}"
                                      SelectionChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged">
                                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```cs
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Items = new List<Model>
        {
            new Model { SelectedName = "b" },
            new Model { SelectedName = "a" }
        };
    }

    public static List<string> Names { get; set; } = new List<string>
    {
        "a", "b"
    };

    public List<Model> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Model
{
    public string SelectedName { get; set; }
}
```

If now I move the list `Names` to the model class instead (which in my case happens to be what I want, as the row itself imposes constraints on the contents of the `ComboBox`) and update the `Binding` accordingly, then I *do* hit the exception, even though, as far as I can tell, the `ComboBox`es involved are as non-empty as in the example above.

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedName}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <!-- Binding below has changed -->
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Names}"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedName}"
                                      SelectionChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged">
                                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```cs
public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Items = new List<Model>
        {
            new Model { SelectedName = "b" },
            new Model { SelectedName = "a" }
        };
    }

    public List<Model> Items { get; set; }
    // Names has been removed here
}

public class Model
{
    public string SelectedName { get; set; }

    // Names moved in here now instead
    public static List<string> Names { get; set; } = new List<string>
    {
        "a", "b"
    };
}
```

All bindings work just the same, the only difference is that there is an instant of time where a `ComboBox` is empty. So the question becomes: What is causing this, and is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: Where are many deferred things in WPF, often solution is to delay action by queuing it via `Dispatcher`. You probably run into virtualization issue, which is by default on for e.g. `ListBox`. The question here is why you use `SelectionChanged` event (btw naming is wrong, `OnXXX` is virtual event riser, not handler)? Perhaps there is better solution for your X problem (see [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/299295)).

Comment: The only reason for using the event here is to provide a minimal working example that highlights the discrepancy between the two cases. In practice, this discrepancy ends up having an impact on code-behind-free approaches; for example, I came across the issue by having a converter on the inner-most binding, and the parameters with which the converter would be invoked would depend on which one of the two approaches was taken.

Comment: Data templates and/or virtualizations are tricky. If you check `DataContext` of `ComboBox` at the moment of exception it will be `{{DisconnectedItem}}` (due to virtualization, data templates or both), you could check this before attempting to do *normal* stuff. If you want to fix converter problem, then be more specific, try to produce [mcve] for that case.